# React Native Dropdown Picker

Tags: javascript, react-native, dropdown

I am using React Native Dropdown Picker and I can list items without a problem. But I want to add an Icon to the items left. How can I achieve that? Here is my example code:

```
<DropDownPicker
                testID="network-dropdown"
                open={networkOpen}
                value={networkValue}
                items={networkItems}
                setOpen={setNetworkOpen}
                setValue={setNetworkValue}
                setItems={setNetworkItems}
                style={$dropdown}
                textStyle={$dropdownText}
                dropDownContainerStyle={$dropdownListContainer}
                itemSeparatorStyle={{
                  borderBottomColor: colors.palette.black,
                  borderBottomWidth: spacing.z,
                }}
                showTickIcon={false}
                zIndex={2000}
                zIndexInverse={2000}
              />
```

Here is my network items:

```
{ label: "Ethereum", value: "eth" },
```

so in that label I want to add Ethereum's icon on its labels left.

I tried renderBadgeItem and many other props but I can't seem to figure it out. I rendered a custom component on dropdown list but when I select that item it displays only the label.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the **items** property of the DropDownPicker component to include an **icon** property. The **icon** property can be a function that returns a JSX element, or it can be a string that refers to the name of an icon component.

```
   {
          label: 'Blue',
          value: 'Blue',
          icon: () => (
             <Ionicons name="md-checkmark-circle" size={32} color="blue" />
          ),
   },
```

here is the example : [DropDownPicker with icons](https://snack.expo.dev/@appdelogico/ce9202)

here is the related documentation: [Doc](https://hossein-zare.github.io/react-native-dropdown-picker-website/docs/advanced/icons)

Comment: what is the way to add/remove padding between items?

Comment: @TanjilHossain You have to pass style object with item. [check this doc](https://hossein-zare.github.io/react-native-dropdown-picker-website/docs/5.3/advanced/list-and-items#styling). 
Also i have added paddingTop: 20 in last item in snack example. [demo](https://snack.expo.dev/fmK581Alo). 
Hope this will help you.